# Do all Android phones tether?

Tags: 10.04, usb, android, usb-drive, tethering

Can I pick up any android phone and connect it to my ubuntu laptop via a usb cable and tether to the internet using the data allowance on my phone contract?  I already know that my contract allows tethering at no additional charge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All android devices tether, its only the provider that block's it .It'd probably work Plug-n-play, it will display as a mobile internet connection on network manager

Comment: Just tried out my wife's htc wildfire and it worked plug and play.  I was pleasantly surprised!!!

Comment: Good to know!..